# Is this ok to replace window with global in an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

Somehow something feels wrong or dirty by doing this, but it seems to be more semantic than using exports or window. Is this ok?

```
(function(global){
  var foo,bar;
  foo = 'Private Var';
  global.bar = 'Hello World';
})(window);
```

Comment: Sure, it's just a var name, so you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: What's the point in replacing window ? I don't see any gain. Is it just in case you inadvertently copy paste your code to node.js ?

Comment: @dystroy I guess it's for consistency on browsers plus non-browser js implementations, such as node.

Comment: That's what I supposed but... This really doesn't seem worth the pain and the additional burden on code readers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is fine. Consider this, though:

```
// global code

(function () {

    var root = this;

    // use root variable to refer to the global object

}).call( this );
```

This pattern does not rely on the `"window"` name, which makes it portable. (The name `"root"` is, of course, arbitrary.)

Comment: Why use `this` and `call`? `(function(global) { ... })(this)` should be fine as well and is more readable to me

Comment: @Bergi I just wrote the exact pattern underscore.js uses. I myself would pass it as an argument, too.

Comment: @Bergi I guess the idea is to explicitly set the `this` value of the function invocation. In your code, the value of `this` in the function body can be either the global object or `undefined` depending on whether strict mode is active, and whether the environment even implements strict mode. In my code the value of `this` is certain. However, leaking the global object into the function can be considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

You're just creating an alias for window by doing this, not replacing it. I like the style. 'global' makes your intention much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you aren't *replacing* the `window`, you're just creating an alias for it.
Your pattern  is good, but I want to make a little suggestion : if you're running that IIFE in the global context, you should pass `this` as the `global` argument and not window :

```
(function(global){

})(this);
```

This helps your code to be more cross-platform, say if you would make a module that runs in the browser but runs on another platform too (say like nodejs or rhino) where the `window` object doesn't exist, or it isn't the global object that youwant it to be.